# Calling ImageView from 2nd java class

Tags: java, android, class, imageview

I have 2 java class in my project
one is called `MainActivity`, and 2nd is called `TicTacToeGame`
now I have called the following function from `MainActivity`:-

```
private TicTacToeGame mGame;
private ImageView mBoardButtons[];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

mBoardButtons = new ImageView[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
    mBoardButtons[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM00);
    mBoardButtons[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM01);
    mBoardButtons[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM02);
    mBoardButtons[9] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM03);
    mBoardButtons[10] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM04);
    mBoardButtons[11] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM05);
    mBoardButtons[18] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM06);
    mBoardButtons[19] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM07);
    mBoardButtons[20] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVGM08);
 }


private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    int location;

    public ButtonClickListener(int location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }

   public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (!mGameOver)
        {
           if (mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
            {
                if (mIsSinglePlayer)
                {
                    setMove(mGame.PLAYER_ONE, location);

                    int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    if (winner == 0)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                        int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                        setMove(mGame.PLAYER_TWO, move);
                        winner = mGame.checkForWinner();
                    }

                    if (winner == 0)
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                    else if (winner == 10)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                        mTieCounter++;
                        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
//                            mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else if (winner == 20)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                        mPlayerOneCounter++;                   
               mPlayerOneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerOneCounter));
//                            mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else if (winner == 30)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                        mPlayerTwoCounter++;
               mPlayerTwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerTwoCounter));
//                            mGameOver = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mIsPlayerOneTurn)
                        setMove(mGame.PLAYER_ONE, location);
                    else
                        setMove(mGame.PLAYER_TWO, location);

                    int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                    if (winner == 0)
                    {
                        if (mIsPlayerOneTurn)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_two);
                            mIsPlayerOneTurn = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_one);
                            mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (winner == 1)
                    {
                        mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                        mTieCounter++;
                        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
    //                            mGameOver = true;
                    }
                    else if (winner == 2)
                    {
                     mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_player_one_wins);
                        mPlayerOneCounter++;
               mPlayerOneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerOneCounter));
  //                            mGameOver = true;
                        mIsPlayerOneTurn = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_player_two_wins);
                        mPlayerTwoCounter++;                            
               mPlayerTwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayerTwoCounter));
    //                            mGameOver = true;
                       mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now it looks for the winner from TicTacToeGame

```
public int checkForWinner()
{
    //set0 win chk
    if ((mBoard[0] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[1] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[2] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[9] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[11] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[18] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[19] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[0] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[9] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[18] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[1] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[19] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[2] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[11] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[0] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[2] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[18] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;
        gameState[0] = 0;

    ImageView img0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageVMain0);
    img0.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
```

How can I write these last lines in `TicTacToeGame` so that I can display `ImageVMain0` in my app?

The error I get is `cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'`

Comment: 2nd java class means 2nd activity

Comment: use ImageView as parameter in method checkForWinner(ImageView view)

Comment: Where did you initalize `mGame`? You could move `mBoardButtons` into `TicTacToeGame` class, yes?

Comment: Ideally if you are doing seperation between your View layer and your business logic layer, just return the winner from checkForWinner method and populate the imageview in your activity itself. Thus your logic becomes isolated and can be individually tested.

Comment: thanks for the replys

Comment: initialize `mGame`  in your  `onCreate()`  method.

Comment: basic point of my app is a tic tac toe game which has multiple games in  one game i mean there are 9 games being played simultaneously that if like i win a set it will mark my sign i.e. X is my sign and i won a game it mean i won a set and it will mark it with big X now i have to win 2 more sets to win the main game

Comment: now while all the thing are working properly i just cant put that big X or O on the set that is where that piece of code i pasted up comes from

Comment: ok show me your complete `logCat` errors.

Comment: i cant just call chechForWinner(ImageView view) cause it is not just one time it is to be loaded 9 times

Comment: without it, I can't help you.

Comment: Logcat:
02-02 18:52:57.132: VERBOSE/ProtocolEngine(24): DownloadRate 104166 bytes per sec. Downloaded Bytes 5643/34714
08-03 13:31:16.196: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2227): HeapWorker thread shutting down
08-03 13:31:16.756: INFO/dalvikvm(2234): Debugger is active
08-03 16:26:45.965: WARN/ActivityManager(564): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-04 16:19:11.166: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4687): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-04 16:24:11.166: ASSERT/Assertion(4687): Expected true but was false

Comment: these are the "Messages Gradle Build"

Comment: Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\auk01\Desktop\GrandTicTacToe\app\src\main\java\com\example\auk01\grandtictactoe\TicTacToeGame.java
Error:(136, 37) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 12.798 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console